# I can't Interpolate from an array . Why is that?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

This is the function inside on ngOnChanges

```
function isCherries(a: any) {
        return a.id === "id#";
      }
```

This is the HTTP Request

```
this.http
    .get(this.datajson).subscribe(sort_data => {
      this.allData = [sort_data as any];

      var all_data = new Array();
      all_data.push(sort_data);      
      var blank = new Array();

      blank.push(all_data[0].country.state[0].city[0].borough.neighborhood.street.find(isCherries));
all_data[0].country.state[0].city[0].borough.neighborhood.street.find(isCherries);
console.log(blank);

      console.log(all_data[0].country.state[1].city[0].borough.neighborhood.street.find(isCherries));
    all_data[0].country.state[1].city[0].borough.neighborhood.street.find(isCherries).find();
    
    

    });
```

When I `console.log(blank)` I could tell that the data is coming back as it should. I could tell that the find() is working as it should.

My issue is now taking that data and displaying it on HTML using *ngFor. I can't figure this out. How do I {{}} that array called **Blank** ?

Comment: well you need to expose blank somehow so your angular rendering sees it....

Comment: We do need more code to understanding your problem. Show the HTML part, and the full .ts part (the relevant stuf ofcourse)